# Socket.io sending lots of request on start up

Tags: node.js, socket.io, request, ejs

I'm writing a Node.js app and as i need to stream data to the browser, i included the `Socket.io` library. Is it correct that as soon as it starts, i get all these request in the console?

```
GET http://192.168.8.115:1337/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LCP0qc- 200 OK 1ms   
GET http://192.168.8.115:1337/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LCP0qd4 200 OK 5ms   
POST http://192.168.8.115:1337/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LCP0qdf&sid=kRNcDo8LvANa39H3AAAC 200 OK 1ms 
GET http://192.168.8.115:1337/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LCP0qdn&sid=kRNcDo8LvANa39H3AAAC 200 OK 1ms  
POST http://192.168.8.115:1337/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LCP0qe4&sid=EYk1kgtAKZ-ju0IqAAAD 200 OK 1ms
GET http://192.168.8.115:1337/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LCP0qeA&sid=EYk1kgtAKZ-ju0IqAAAD 200 OK 1ms  
GET http://192.168.8.115:1337/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LCP0qeo&sid=kRNcDo8LvANa39H3AAAC 200 OK 130ms    
GET http://192.168.8.115:1337/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LCP0qfD&sid=EYk1kgtAKZ-ju0IqAAAD 200 OK 128ms
```

I'm requesting the EJS template through this code:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render(__dirname + '/views/index');
});
```

And this is how i start `Socket.io` connection:

```
var socket = io.connect('/'+ip);
socket.on('update', function(data) {
    $('#dateTime').html(data.time);
});
```

It looks very weird to me and i didn't find any docs about this searching on google!

Answer (score 0):

This is correct and expected behaviour.

The first package is a connect package.

It looks like you are connecting from two different browsers (or two different tabs) at the same time. The `t=` argument is a unique number to break any caching.

The first `POST` with each sid is the connecting. The following `GET` is just polling, while the `POST` are `pong` packets, to say that the connection is still live.

If you upgrade the sockets to websockets it stops hitting the webserver all the time.

Comment: Mmm...the strange thing is that i was connecting from 2 pcs but i was launching a single connection from each machine (1 browser, 1 tab). If i try now without any change to the code i'm having 3 get requests and 1 post, so something different. That's why i say this is a strange behaviour. I'll try this websocket thing...would you recommend any particular document about it?

Comment: socket.io will upgrade to websockets automatically, if it's possible on your network. Could it be that you initialized to socket.io instances, and was hitting your server with two connections?

Comment: how could this be? my code is all in the question and there was only 1 browser per pc pointing at that page of the server...

Comment: Things running in backgroun on your browser? Bug in your browser? The browser loading an old version of your file? Difficult to say unless I'm sitting at your computer.